# WPF After login,store username to another xaml

Tags: wpf, datastore

I have 2 xaml window and i want to store data between windows.How can i do?

Comment: There are many ways of doing it. You can pass it on the constructor as a parameter to the other window.

Comment: need to write something in xml/textbox?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Refer the below code sample for passing using constructor.

```
<Window x:Class="DelegateComd_Learning.Login"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Login" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Username"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtUsername" Width="100"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Login" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

```
public partial class Login : Window
{
    public Login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window1 win = new Window1(txtUsername.Text);
        win.Show();
    }
}
<Window x:Class="DelegateComd_Learning.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <TextBlock x:Name="txtDisplayUsername"/>
</Grid>
```

```
 public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1(string username)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        txtDisplayUsername.Text = username;
    }
}
```